# Copying an ElementName binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, wpf-controls

I have a TextBox (TB1) which has its Text value bound to another TextBox (TB2) using ElementName="TB2" and Path="Text".

I then have a third TextBox (TB3) which I am SetBinding in the code behind to TB1 which I had hoped would allow me edit TB3 and both TB1 & TB2 would also reflect the changes due to the binding being (theoretically) the same for all.

I can edit TB1 and TB2 is updated (and vice versa), but TB3 never displays / updates the value.

I can only think it's because TB1 binding is using ElementName and not a DependencyProperty?

Is it possible to copy the binding of an element bound using ElementName?

```
<TextBox Name="TB1">
    <Binding ElementName="TB2" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
</TextBox>
<TextBox Name="TB2">
    <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
</TextBox>
```

Then in code behind I have:

```
BindingExpression bindExpression = TB1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
if (bindExpression != null && bindExpression.ParentBinding != null && bindExpression.ParentBinding.Path != null)
{
    TB3.DataContext = TB1.DataContext;
    TB3.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bindExpression.ParentBinding);
}
```

---

Typically just found with testing just now that this does work if within the same xaml. However, I have TB3 in its own window as below, and the textbox is never bound correctly.. what am I missing?

```
if (bindExpression != null && bindExpression.ParentBinding != null && bindExpression.ParentBinding.Path != null)
{
    PopupWindow wnd = new PopupWindow();
    wnd.DataContext = TB1.DataContext;
    wnd.TB3.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bindExpression.ParentBinding);
    wnd.Show();
}
```

---

I'm not 100% sure why but this did the trick, it seems to do the same binding as SetBinding but with the source being set to the DataItem, but it gave me the required result... Thanks Klaus78..

```
if (bindExpression != null && bindExpression.ParentBinding != null && bindExpression.ParentBinding.Path != null)
    {
        PopupWindow wnd = new PopupWindow();
        Binding b = new Binding();
        b.Source = bindExpression.DataItem; //TB1;
        b.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
        b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        wnd.TB3.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
        wnd.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your new window you bind `TB3.Text` to `TB2.Text`

In practice for TB3.Text you have a Binding objet where `Element=TB2` and `Path=Text`. The problem is that in the visual tree of the new window there is not element with name `TB2` and so you get a binding error if you look at Visual Studio output debug.

Also notice that `TB1.DataContext` is null. On the other hand this command is useless because the binding class has already the `Element` property set which is the binding source.

I think you cannot simply copy the binding from TB1 to TB3. You anyhow need to create a new Binding object for TB3 like

```
Window2 wnd = new Window2();
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = TB1;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
wnd.TB3.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
wnd.Show();
```

Could some code like that be helpful for you?

Comment: Thanks Klaus78, that led me to a solution... please see edited question.